# C#: Remove duplicate elements of Dictionary using properties contained in Value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObjectWithDates Item1 = new ObjectWithDates(new DateTime(2015,8,20), //very beginning of today (duplicate)
            new DateTime(2015,8,20,1,0,0)); //today at 1:00 AM (date to consider when removing duplicates)

        ObjectWithDates Item2 = new ObjectWithDates(new DateTime(2015, 8, 20), //very beginning of today (duplicate)
            new DateTime(2015, 8, 20, 15, 0, 0)); //today at 3:00 PM  (date to consider when removing duplicates)

        SortedDictionary<string, ObjectWithDates> Dict = new SortedDictionary<string, ObjectWithDates>();
        Dict.Add("Item1", Item1);
        Dict.Add("Item2", Item2);


        //to remove duplicates using GroupBy:
        Dictionary<string, ObjectWithDates> UniqueValues = Dict.GroupBy(x => x.Value.DateToRemoveDuplicates)
                    .Select(group => group.First())
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        Dict = new SortedDictionary<string, ObjectWithDates>(UniqueValues);

    }

    public class ObjectWithDates
    {
        public DateTime DateToRemoveDuplicates {get; set;}
        public DateTime DateForRemovalComparison { get; set; }

        public ObjectWithDates(DateTime DateToRemoveDuplicates, DateTime DateForRemovalComparison)
        {
            this.DateToRemoveDuplicates = DateToRemoveDuplicates;
            this.DateForRemovalComparison = DateForRemovalComparison;
        }
    }
}
```

The above example removes one of the duplicate entries by grouping on `DateToRemoveDuplicates` and taking `First()`. I am wondering if there is a quick (and perhaps less ham-handed) way to remove the duplicate according to `DateForRemovalComparison` (i.e. remove the earlier of the two `DateTimes`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ like:

```
var newDictionay = oldDictionary.GroupBy(n => n.Value)
    .Select(grp => grp.First()).ToDictionary(n => n.Key, n => n.Value);
```

Comment: This indeed appears to be a cleaner way to do what I was doing with LINQ above, but I have no idea why this works...since we are just grouping by n.Value, how does it decide which `KeyValuePair` to remove?